# not able to reset heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I recently upgraded from a hobby-dev plan to a hobby-basic plan but something really weird is happening. I have a ton of data and my site works just fine but when I do heroku pg:info, it says I have 0 tables and 0 rows:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.3.2
Created:     2014-01-08 19:23 UTC
Data Size:   6.4 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
Region:      Europe

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.3.2
Created:     2013-12-10 03:27 UTC
Data Size:   7.4 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

It also says I'm on plan: dev, which isn't right. I'm obviously saving to a database but I'm not sure which one. How do I get the right database to show its stats? Also, how do I reset that database?

EDIT: I should mention it clearly says I'm paying $9/month for the hobby basic plan under addons:

Heroku Postgres :: Navy Hobby-basic

Comment: Really an issue for Heroku support alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a support ticket so we can help you and know what your app is.

Comment: ok I submitted a ticket...just figured i was doing something wrong and didn't want to bother heroku